# reGex Inverse selection for emoticon

Tags: javascript, regex, utf, emoticons

```
(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])
```

I have this regex to select the emoticons on an input. 
Tried doing inverse selection on the above regex and is not returning the intended output

```
([^\u00a9]|[^\u00ae]|[^\u2000-\u3300]|[^\ud83c][^\ud000-\udfff]|[^\ud83d][^\ud000-\udfff]|[^\ud83e][^\ud000-\udfff])

or

[^(\u00a9|\u00ae|[\u2000-\u3300]|\ud83c[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83d[\ud000-\udfff]|\ud83e[\ud000-\udfff])]
```

Anyone knows the correct approach for this?

https://www.regextester.com/106421
Expected output would be to select the inverse of the emoticons or the alphanumeric chars only

Trying to avoid javascript Functions and trying to resolve using only a regex query

Comment: What about `s.split(your_regex)`? You may even `.join("")` the resulting array to get a string back.

Comment: A bit restricted on the use of javascript functions and would like to have a regex only solution.

Comment: So, please post the code showing what you **can** use, sample string and expected output.

Comment: will do, thanks for pointing that out

Comment: Good question... @MichaelRosales